# How to get a file exist with an extension of .txt in a folder without using opendir and stat using C programming?

Tags: c, file, directory

I have a folder named as TestProgram where I want to know whether there is a file named as a.txt exist inside the folder or not. How I suppose to do that without using opendir and stat function but using fopen in C programming?

I've tried to search from the forums where there is a lot of the solutions are included directory and stat() function as I do not want to use opendir() and stat().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Concatenate the directory name with the file name, and then try to `fopen()` the file:

```
const char directory[] = "TestProgram";
const char filename[] = "a.txt";
char pathname[1024];

snprintf(pathname, sizeof(pathname), "%s/%s", directory, filename);

FILE *fp = fopen(pathname, "r");
if (fp == NULL)
    printf("File %s does not exist\n", pathname);
else
{
    printf("File %s exists and is readable\n", pathname);
    fclose(fp);
}
```

You could also use `access(pathname, F_OK)` to test whether the file exists, though it is a subtly different test under some special circumstances.  Those apply only if the program that is running is SUID; it tests whether the real UID instead of the effective UID — or the real GID or one of the auxilliary GID values instead of the effective GID — can access the file.

The code should check the return value from `snprintf()` to ensure that the name was not truncated.  When the path name array is that big and the names that small, it isn't necessary, but when you're not sure about the size of the directory and file name, you should do the testing.

Comment: May I know what is the function of char pathname[1024]? Is the pathname used to store the concatenated of files? :)

Comment: It's an array of characters that is used to hold the combined directory and file name.  After the `snprintf()` call, it would contain `TestProgram/a.txt`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and the solutions, it does solve my problems.

Comment: May I know if I want to get .txt file instead of using a.txt file? Can I do that?

Comment: What do you mean?  Finding a specific file name such as `a.txt` is easy.  If you want to look for the name `.txt`, you eliminate the `a`.  If you want to look for any name ending `.txt` (so `a.txt` or `bc.txt` or `catastrophic.txt`), then you can't sensibly try all the alternative names — for that, you probably do need to use [`readdir()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/readdir.html) et al. or one of the other specialized POSIX directory scanning functions such as [`scandir()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/scandir.html).

Comment: How I suppose to do that with the similar problem above by using readdir() to find all the file name ending with .txt?

Comment: Well, you probably right. Thanks for the help and I appreciate it very much. Thank you.